# Using sql group by and having

Tags: group-by, having-clause

I'm quite new to SQL and I am trying to answer the exercise 8 of [SQL ZOO](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUM_and_COUNT), but I am missing something. Could you please help me?

```
List the continents that have a total population of at least 100 million.
```

What I am trying is:

```
select continent
from world
group by continent 
having count(population) >= 100000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was to use COUNT instead of SUM.

Try the following:

```
select continent
from world
group by continent
having sum(population) >= 100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT continent, SUM(population) AS 'total population'
  FROM world
  GROUP BY continent
  HAVING SUM(population) >= 500000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a five year old question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. The question does state to list the continents that have a total population of at least 100 million, so this answer both adds a feature that wasn't asked for, the total population, and doesn't generate the correct answer as it is comparing to 500 million.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT continent
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING SUM(population) >= 100000000
```

Please, try this chunk